# How can I check to see if a Rails.cache key exists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm trying to replicate the following Rails method, but using JQuery:

```
Rails.cache.exist?("ped_basic")
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't use Rails, but from the looks of it that data is stored in the server's memory, meaning you wouldn't be able to access it with javascript other than by sending an ajax request to a rails script.

Comment: How would you recommend I do this (the ajax request to the rails script)?

Comment: Why not output the value of that method on the page, possibly as a data attribute of something so that you can then access it? Here's a tutorial on ajax: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am still experimenting with the optimal way to do this, but I've ended up using the ['Gon' gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to create a variable in my controller method (before_filter) that is able to be referenced by Rails as well as by jQuery.

In my controller method, I set my cache key equal to a gon.variable value, then can access the variable in jQuery via the same gon.variable name.

In other words:

```
#Controller method
before_filter :set_gon_vars

def set_gon_vars
  gon.variable1 = Rails.cache.exist?("cache1")
  gon.variable2 = Rails.cache.exist?("cache2")
  gon.variable3 = Rails.cache.exist?("cache3")
end
```

The the variables can be accessed in my coffeescript code by simply referencing the same gon.variable name.